# Define a macro for citation aliasing

Tags: biblatex

How can I define a macro for the following citation

```
\defcitealias{author:year}{AuthorFirstName AuthorLastName}\citetalias{author:year} \citep{author:year}
```

such that `\cmdAlias{author:year}{AuthorFirstName AuthorLastName}` executes the above command?

Comment: You mean `\newcommand{\cmdAlias}[2]{\defcitealias{#1}{#2}\citetalias{#1} \citep{#1}}`?

Comment: @Werner: This is the answer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Without more information, you could use

```
\newcommand{\cmdAlias}[2]{\defcitealias{#1}{#2}\citetalias{#1} \citep{#1}}
```

such that `\cmdAlias{author:year}{AuthorFirstName AuthorLastName}` executes the above command.